# How to display posts by current user/author in a custom page template?

Tags: posts, query-posts, author, get-posts, listing

I am a trying to create a dashboard like custom page template that list post of of the current logged in user. I've tried to find a solution on the net. but none were appropriate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
    <?php           
    endwhile;

else :

    echo "not logged in";

endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

To include custom post time in the `$author_query array`, add another `key=>value` element to `$author_query` array.

Example:

```
$author_query = array(
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'author' => $current_user->ID,
   'post_type'=>'your custom post type name'
);
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Just a few notes to get you started: 1.) Always properly explain what your code does and how it works 2.) Please work on your code format when adding code. If you add code, highlight it in the code editor and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. Thank you