# List of pages of a specific user

Tags: pages

How to get list of pages of a specific user? And show them in a WordPress page.

Say i have `page1` , `page2` , `page3` , `page4` created by `User1` .
How to list them in a page like this:

1. page1   created: 1/1/2018 - 11:12 AM
2. page2   created: 2/1/2018 - 10:00 PM
3. page3   created: 3/1/2018 - 09:11 AM
4. page4   created: 4/1/2018 - 12:12 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to do it.

Here is the code:

```
$author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => 1,'post_type' => 'PAGE');
$author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
?>
    ■ <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br />      
<?php           
endwhile;
```

more information: [see here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23829/how-to-display-posts-by-current-user-author-in-a-custom-page-template)